# How To Bold, Italic And Underline The Same Selected Text in Python Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I created three different buttons in my program under the menu. Each of the button can perform their functions perfectly. However,when I bold an underlined text, the text will set to underline without bold. My problem is the selected text can only perform one selected style.How can I retain the previous style of the word and adding the new style?

Comment: Can you show us what you have done?

Comment: The answer depends a lot on how you're applying the style. Please [edit] . your question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try :

```
tkFont.Font(family="font_name", font_size=10, weight=tkFont.BOLD,
        slant=tkFont.ITALIC)
```

You can see more [at](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-widget-styling.htm).

Comment: def bold():
    try:
        current_taga= text.tag_names("sel.first")
        if "bt" in current_taga :
            text.tag_remove("bt" , "sel.first" , "sel.last")
            text.tag_config("bt" , font=("Arial" , 10 , "bold"))
        else:
            text.tag_add("bt" , "sel.first" , "sel.last")
            text.tag_config("bt" , font=("Arial" , 10 , "bold"))
    except:
        pass

Comment: def italic():
    try:
        current_taag= text.tag_names("sel.first")
        if "bt" in current_taag :
            text.tag_remove("bt" , "sel.first" , "sel.last")
            text.tag_config("bt" , font=("Arial" , 10 , "italic"))
        else:
            text.tag_add("bt" , "sel.first" , "sel.last")
            text.tag_config("bt" , font=("Arial" , 10 , "italic"))
    except:
        pass

Comment: i am using inside the function... like if i click on Bold then Italic , it will turn into Bold + Italic